# How to prompt permission dialog for notification listener

Tags: android, android-permissions, notification-listener

Is there any way to automatically give permission of `notification` listener or to prompt permission dialog like this in > android M:

Permission dialog:

[image: permission dialog]

Currently i am using intent for allowing notification to app like:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Check for runtime permission

Comment: hope this tutorial will help
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/

Comment: I did but i was unable to resolve permission for specifically for Notification Listener

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to ask for **Push Notification** permissions same as we don't ask for permission to gain access of the **INTERNET**.

While ***Contacts/Locations/SMS/PhoneCall*** are accessing user's data, so we always need to ask to user to give us the permission.

Hope you get the point. for more info please visit [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview).

Comment: no i am not asking for push notifications. I m asking for notification listener access to application. As i am doing it manually i want to prompt permission message

Comment: I don't think that you need permission for that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is. Running your code snippet should open the permission page for Notification access. Is that not happening or do you want a dialog like other permissions?

Presumably you're trying to extend NotificationListener. Have you included

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
      android:label="@string/service_name"
      android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
 </intent-filter>
```

in your manifest?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). I have added this service in manifest. I am able to open the activity to allow notification listener. But i want to prompt user to accept the permission of notification access when app launches. Like other permission message like locations, gallery etc

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get the actual permission dialog in the same way you would for location etc.

That doesn't mean you can't create your own similar one though, just create an AlertDialog that uses the intent in your OP to launch the activity.